# How to create a class that asks user for input for Instantiation

Tags: python, class, constructor

I am writing a code that should create a user and add it to a database. A constructor has the properties of the user but instead of instantiating the object in the code, I would like it to ask the user for the names, age and color.

```
class Person:

  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, color):
    self.first_name = first_name 
    self.last_name = last_name 
    self.age = age 
    self.color = color 

person_one = Person("FName", "LName", 4, "Blue")

print(person_one.color)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like a simple application of [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: I would like to write a method inside the class that does that. so that when i call the method, it asks for the various fields.

Answer (score 0):

> **Python input() Function**
>
> The input() function allows user input.
>
> **Syntax:** `input(prompt)`
>
> Parameter:
>
> *prompt*:  A String, representing a default message before the input.

```
first_name = input('Enter first_name:')
last_name = input('Enter last_name:')
age = input('Enter age:')
color = input('Enter color:')

person_one = Person(first_name,last_name, age, color)
```